# List contents of varnish cache?

Tags: varnish

Is there a way to list the contents of the varnish cache storage? Also, it would be nice to somehow list the most frequent cache hits.

I found a way to see the most frequent cache misses by listing what is being sent to the backend with:

```
varnishtop -b -i TxURL
```

It would be very useful to see what are my top cache hits URLs.

Edit: I am using version: varnish-3.0.3 revision 9e6a70f

Comment: What version of varnish do you have?

Comment: varnishd (varnish-3.0.3 revision 9e6a70f)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this you can help:

You can use the parameter "Varnish:hitmiss" of varnishncsa.

First capture a sample of logs with:

`varnishncsa -F '%U%q %{Varnish:hitmiss}x' -n NAME -w /path/requests.logs`

and then:

`sort -k 1 /path/requests.logs | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n -r | head -25`

Answer (score 3):

This feature is not included in Varnish, but you can easily add some scripting to do so.

- First thing you need, is to launch varnishncsa as a service and write output in a daily file.
- Then add to the default output format at least `%{Varnish:hitmiss}x` and `%U` (see [varnishncsa doc](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishncsa.html))
- Finally, write some scripts to compute your top URL for example something as below :

> ```
> # we admit %{Varnish:hitmiss}x is the first column and %U the second
> awk '$0 ~ / hit / { arr[$8]=arr[$8]+1 }END{ for(k in arr) { print arr[k]";"k } }' varnishncsa.log|sort -k 1 -nr |head
> ```

And feel free to update for your specific needs..